# QT QNetworkReply and Php

Tags: php, qt

i'm trying to connect to a php page.

doesn't matter what i do, but QNetworkReply is always empty.

this is my code, hope someone got an idea.

```
QUrl url("http://mysite.it/interface.php");
QNetworkRequest request(url);

request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
QUrlQuery params;
//list of params 


url.setQuery(params);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));

manager->post(request,params.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8());

connect(this, SIGNAL(confirm_signal()), reciver, SLOT(recive_confirm()));
```

this is the slot for the reply

```
    void database::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
    if(reply->error())
        {
        qDebug() << "ERROR!";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();

        }
    else {
        qDebug()<< reply->readAll().toInt();
        qDebug()<< reply->readAll().trimmed();
        QByteArray array = reply->readAll();
        QString str(array);
        reply->deleteLater();
        qDebug() << "array" <<array;
        qDebug() <<"string" <<str;

        QString str2 = QString::fromUtf8(array.data(), array.size());

        qDebug() <<str2;
        int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
        qDebug() << QVariant(statusCode).toString();
        emit confirm_signal();
    }
}
```

all the qDebug() gives "" as answer, except for the status code that is "200".

```
<?php
json_encode("Ok");
?>
```

Comment: is the php code at the end the contents of `interface.php` file?

Comment: Yes, to be honest, google did not provide to me any clue about how to give answer back..so tested with echo and json_encode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your current `interface.php` code does not output anything, it just calculates the JSON string (and does send it back), you have to use `echo`.

```
<?php
echo json_encode("Ok");
?>
```

**Edit:** There is another error in your `replyFinished` slot, when you call [`readAll`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll), currently available data in the device is returned. And the next time you call it, only newly available data is returned.

So, by doing `qDebug()<< reply->readAll().toInt();` you are reading currently available data, and you don't save it anywhere, you just convert it to an int (which cannot be done since the data is `"Ok"` and [`toInt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toInt) returns 0), and the next `readAll()` returns an empty `QByteArray` since `"Ok"` was read in the previous call, I think what you meant to write is this:

```
else {
    QByteArray array = reply->readAll();
    qDebug()<< array.toInt();
    qDebug()<< array.trimmed();
    QString str(array);
    reply->deleteLater();
    qDebug() << "array" <<array;
    qDebug() <<"string" <<str;

    QString str2 = QString::fromUtf8(array.data(), array.size());

    qDebug() <<str2;
    int statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    qDebug() << QVariant(statusCode).toString();
    emit confirm_signal();
}
```

Comment: I agree with u, but the point is that i've already tested with that too.